# What is "Soft Coding", really?

Tags: design

In [this article](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Soft_Coding) by Alex Papadimoulis, you can see this snippet:

```
private void attachSupplementalDocuments()
{
  if (stateCode == "AZ" || stateCode == "TX") {

    //SR008-04X/I are always required in these states
    attachDocument("SR008-04X");
    attachDocument("SR008-04XI");
  }

  if (ledgerAmnt >= 500000) {
    //Ledger of 500K or more requires AUTHLDG-1A
    attachDocument("AUTHLDG-1A");
  }

  if (coInsuredCount >= 5  && orgStatusCode != "CORP") {
    //Non-CORP orgs with 5 or more co-ins require AUTHCNS-1A
    attachDocument("AUTHCNS-1A");
  }
}
```

I really don't understand this article.

I quote:

> If every business rule constant was stored in some configuration file, life would be much [more (*sic*)] difficult for everyone maintaining the software: there’d be a lot of code files that shared one, big file (or, the converse, a whole lot of tiny configuration files); deploying changes to the business rules require not new code, but manually changing the configuration files; and debugging is that much more difficult.

This is an argument against having the "500000" constant integer in a configuration file, or the "AUTHCNS-1A" and other string constants.

*How can this be a bad practice?*

In this snippet, "500000" is not a number. It's not, for example, the same as:

```
int doubleMe(int a) { return a * 2;}
```

where 2, is a number that needs not be abstracted. Its use is obvious, and it does not represent something that may be reused later on.

On the contrary, "500000" is not simply a number. It's a significant value, one that represents the idea of a breakpoint in functionality. This number could be used in more than one place, but it's not the number that you're using; it's the idea of the limit/borderline, below which one rule applies, and above which another.

How is referring to it from a configuration file, or even a `#define`, `const` or whatever your language provides, worse than including its value? If later on the program, or some other programmer, also requires that borderline, so that the software makes another choice, you're screwed (because **when** it changes, nothing guarantees you that it will change in both files). That's clearly worse for debugging.

In addition, if tomorrow, the government demands "From 5/3/2050, you need to add AUTHLDG-122B instead of AUTHLDG-1A", this string constant is not a simple string constant. It's one that represents an idea; it's just the current value of that idea (which is "the thing that you add if the ledger is above 500k").

Let me clarify. I'm not saying that the article is wrong; I just don't get it; maybe it's not too well explained (at least for my thinking).

I do understand that replacing every possible string literal or numerical value with a constant, define, or configuration variable, is not only not necessary, but overcomplicates things, but this particular example does not seem to fall under this category. How do you know that you will not need it later on? Or someone else for that matter?

Comment: Play the puzzle: what would be a good name for those numbers? I think you'll find that either the name adds no value whatsoever, or it describes everything the code is already describing and often while *adding* ambiguity ("LedgerLimitForAuthDlg1A"?). I found the article brilliant *exactly* because of how relevant is this. I've maintained systems that have used both approaches, and I can tell you that business rules belong in code - it makes them much easier to track, maintain and understand. When you use configuration, you better make it count - it's much more expensive.

Comment: Configuration should be reserved for things that need to be configured. If the business rules aren't configurable in general, putting bits of it in configuration anyway buys you nothing.

Comment: For suitably advanced languages, configuration takes form of actual subroutines and not strings.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The author is warning against premature abstraction.

The line `if (ledgerAmt > 500000)` looks like the kind of business rule that you would expect to see for large complex business sytems whose requirements are incredibly complex yet precise and well-documented.

Typically those kinds of requirements are exceptional/edge cases rather than usefully reusable logic.    Those requirements are typically owned and maintained by business analysts and subject matter experts, rather than by engineers

*(Note that 'ownership' of requirements by Business Analysts/experts in these cases typically occurs where developers working in specialist fields don't have sufficient domain expertise; although I would still expect full communication/cooperation between developers and the domain experts to protect against ambiguous or poorly written requirements.)*

When maintaining systems whose requirements are packed full of edge-cases and highly complex logic, there is usually no way to usefully abstract that logic or make it more maintainable;  attempts to try building abstractions can easily backfire - not just resulting in wasted time, but also resulting in less maintainable code.

> How is referring to it from a config file, or even a #define, const or whatever your language provides, worse than including its value? If later on the program, or some other programmer, also requires that borderline, so that the software makes another choice, you're screwed (because when it changes, nothing guarantees you that it will change in both files). That's clearly worse for debugging.

This kind of code tends to be guarded by the fact that the code itself probably has a one-to-one mapping to requirements;  i.e. when a developer *knows* that the `500000` figure appears twice in the requirements, that developer also knows that it appears twice in the code.

Consider the other (equally likely) scenario where `500000` appears in multiple places in the requirements document, but the Subject Matter Experts decide to only change one of them; there you have an even worse risk that somebody changing the `const` value might not realise the `500000` is used to mean different things - so the developer changes it in the one and only place he/she finds it in the code, and ends up breaking something which they didn't realise they had changed.

This scenario happens a lot in bespoke legal/financial software (e.g. insurance quotation logic) - people who write such documents aren't engineers, and they have no problem copy+pasting entire chunks of the spec, modifying a few words/numbers, but leaving most of it the same.

In those scenarios, the best way to deal with copy-paste requirements is to write copy-paste code, and to make the code look as similar to the requirements (including hard-coding all the data) as possible.

The reality of such requirements is that they don't usually stay copy+paste for long, and the values sometimes change on a regular basis, but they often don't change in tandem, so trying to rationalise or abstract those requirements out or simplify them any way ends up creating more of a maintenance headache than just translating requirements verbatim into code.

Comment: A  Domain Specific Language (DSL) can be a good way to make the code read more like the requirement document.

Comment: Another advantage of a DSL is that also makes it harder to accidentally mix application, presentation, or persistence logic with the business rules.

Comment: @Ian going from Ewan's answer, that's exactly what the article is arguing against.

Comment: @OrangeDog, the article is arguing again separating the logic of the app from config information.   A DLS done right allows the "boarding bits", e.g. data access, logging, etc to be separated from the interesting logic.

Comment: Thinking that your application is special enough to warrant its own DSL is *usually* hubris.

Comment: @Ian You still have to be careful to make sure the DSL is worth it, though - it's a trade-off between the cost of having Yet Another Language and the cost of having to use a language that might be less well suited than your DSL. In practice, you'll find that the only DSL you need is "a set of functions in your language of choice", and it integrates a whole lot better in the whole infrastructure - painless unit testing, simple build process, debugging...

Comment: `Those requirements are typically owned and maintained by business analysts and subject matter experts, rather than by engineers` which is not always a good idea. Sometimes the act of turning those requirements into code will reveal corner cases where the requirements are either not well defined or are defined in such a way that it goes against the business interest. If the business analysts and developers can co-operate on achieving a common goal, then a lot of problems can be avoided.

Comment: @kasperd I think you misunderstand somewhat; I'm not talking about ordinary software product specifications, but business rules specifications which are used as the basis for writing/updating business rule logic.   For example, consider a complex statistical model used to calculate insurance premiums; those models can't just be changed to make it easier to write the software.

Comment: @BenCottrell I wasn't suggesting to change the rules to make it easier to write the software. But when you have lots of conditionals in the rules it is entirely possible that some interaction between those was missed when defining the rules in the first place. But as you turn the specification into code, the developer is bound to notice that there is a possible interaction between those conditions. At this point it is possible that the developer finds that a strict interpretation of the specification leads to an unintentional price that would allow customers to game the system.

Comment: @kasperd If a developer has queries like that on requirements which they don't own, why couldn't that just be discussed with the Business Analyst?      developers in specialist fields often aren't experts in those fields, so aren't really qualified to make those requirements changes themselves.

Comment: @BenCottrell Which is why I suggested that those people co-operate.

Comment: @kasperd Maybe I'm missing something? your original comment was regarding ownership of the requirements?

Comment: @BenCottrell My concern is just that someone could interpret *ownership* to mean that the business analysts decide on some rules without seeking feedback from the developers who will eventually implement them.

Comment: @kasperd Aha, I see now, that wasn't my intended interpretation, editing to clarify.

Comment: `This kind of code tends to be guarded by the fact that the code itself probably has a one-to-one mapping to requirements; i.e. when a developer knows that the 500000 figure appears twice in the requirements, that developer also knows that it appears twice in the code.` No. Absolutely no. If that 500000 figure appears twice in the requirements, it should appear twice in the **tests**. I can't, in good conscience, condone code like this.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 to clarify again, the answer is specifically about the kinds of business logic for specialist domains (as per the article in the question). This is a very different issue to generic software requirements or 'user data'. For example, consider a hard `£500,000` upper-limit for two different Home insurance schemes, where the limit needs to be defined in the business rule logic for automatic insurance quotes. It would be worse to refactor into a single const or configurable value, because the business model for one of those home insurance schemes is likely to change in isolation.

Comment: @BenCottrell While I understand what you're saying, there should be a one-to-one relationship between spec values and constant names. In your case, if you had two different home insurance schemes, you would have two different constants (even if they happened to have the same value). Further, you would use these constants in your tests. That "hard upper limit" will change, and when it does, it's logical to change the constants that align with the spec, not just numbers.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 That's fine until you suddenly find yourself trying to maintain many hundreds of these constant names.   For every single one you need to try to think of a useful, intuitive name which both communicates its intent and its meaning to other developers without being too vague or too verbose, or without being easily confused with other names;  But what's the benefit when not saving time writing the code, not making it easier to faster to change, or making it easier to read or understand; not actually making it any more maintainable at all.

Comment: .. In fact, you might be making things take longer, and making the code less maintainable - which is the whole point of the article;  developers tend to have an irrational "fear" of hard-coded values, even when hard-coded values are the most readable, maintainable, logical, sensible and pragmatic way to write code.

Answer (score 46):

The article has a good point. How can it be a bad practice to extract constants to a configuration file? It can be a bad practice if it complicates the code unnecessarily. Having a value directly in code is much simpler than having to read it from a configuration file, and the code as written is easy to follow.

> In addition, tomorrow, the government goes "From 5/3/2050, you need to
>   add AUTHLDG-122B instead of AUTHLDG-1A".

Yeah, then you change the code. The point of the article is that it is not more complicated to change code than changing a configuration file.

The approach described in the article does not scale if you get more complex logic, but the point is that you have to make a judgment call, and sometimes the simplest solution simply is the best.

> How do you know that you will not need it later on? Or someone else
>   for that matter?

This is the point of the YAGNI principle. Don't design for an unknown future which may turn out completely diffent, design for the present. You are correct that *if* the value 500000 is used several places in the program it should of course be extracted to a constant. But this is not the case in the code in question.

Softcoding is really a question of **seperation of concerns**. You softcode information which you know *might change independently* from the core application logic. You would never hardcode a connection string to a database, because you know it might change independently from the application logic and you will need to differentiate it for different environments. In a web app we like to separate business logic from html templates and style sheets, because they might change independently and even be changed by different people.

But in the case in the code sample, the hardcoded strings and numbers are an integral part of the application logic. It is conceivable that one file might change its name due to some policy change outside your control, but it is just as conceivable that we need to add a new if-branch checking for a different condition. Extracting the file names and numbers actually breaks cohesion in this case.

Comment: Don't code preemptively if you are not 80%+ sure that future will happen, and by the time you finished the future analysis to reach that 80%+ figure you usually used up more time that what would be needed to refactor the present-adjusted code. YAGNI indeed. +1'd (p.s.: 80% is a madeup number. Usually 90% of those random statistics are madeup anyway).

Comment: Often it is a lot more complicated to change code than a configuration file. You may need a developer and a build system / release cycle for the former, while the latter only requires changing a number in a box in a friendly config UI.

Comment: What happens if the legislature of one of those states decides to change that (purely arbitrary) 500,000 to 650,000?

Comment: @jamesqf 500,000 -> 650,000? Easy, change the config file. 500,000 -> (some expression relating total net worth of accountholder)? *"What the hell is a typecast error?"*

Comment: @OrangeDog Yeah, that's how it looks at first. But if you do things like this, the config UI is going to be anything *but* friendly, with hundreds of totally meaningless text-boxes asking you for who knows what. And now you have to build the UI, and document it. Mind you, that doesn't mean configuration is never a good way to go - there's cases where it's absolutely the right choice. But not in *any* of the examples in the article. And when was the last time a legislation changed just the number? The last time VAT rules changed here, we had to redo all the calculations anyway.

Comment: @Luuan OTOH last time they changed here, we just had to replace 17.5 with 20.

Comment: @OrangeDog: You are assuming, here, that the software's configuration provides you with the necessary hooks for the check you need to make. Note how in the OP each and every `if` is based on a different variable! If the variable you need is not accessible from the configuration, you need to modify the software anyway.

Comment: @OrangeDog so you are suggesting that there should be significant changes to the *logic* of a software application, without a dev/qa/release cycle and appropriate testing?

Comment: No, I'm just disagreeing with the blanket statement "it is not more complicated to change code than changing a configuration file"

Comment: @brian_o: It's a little more complicated than that.  You've got a special case that applies to two state codes, now one of those states changes its rules.  Now you have to find that special case (which may occur more than once) and rewrite the code...

Comment: @OrangeDog. "...we just had to replace 17.5 with 20." And if you had done it in code, it would be "...we just had to replace 17.5 with 20, then recompile." Now what? Testing and deployment of the new rules. You're going to have to do that no matter what anyway; *those* are the hard parts, not recompilation.

Comment: @Luaan, **"...now you have to build the UI, and document it."**  In my opinion this is the *crucial* point.  If you translate the requirements/legislation directly into code, then when someone asks you "Where is the documentation?" you can say "Read the legislation."  The legislation changes, you change the source, you're done.  Otherwise: the legislation changes, you change the source, you change the config file, you change the config UI, you change the config UI documentation....

Comment: @OrangeDog Yeah, well, I've had to maintain lots of code that handled 20% VAT. When that changed to 21%, a lot of the assumptions no longer worked - in particular, withoutVAT->withVAT is no longer equivalent to withVAT->withoutVAT due to rounding. Sure, that rounding is specified as part of the legislation, so it wouldn't break if it were implemented as specified, but the guys who wrote the code never read the legislation - they just did 20% VAT. And it worked. That said, the algorithm changed in the past. As did deciding when to apply 5% (now 10/15%) and when 20% (now 21%) VAT.

Comment: You all seem to be assuming there's one guy who does all the work, whereas often there's a whole team for each step. If the compliance team finds a value doesn't match the spec, it's less complicated for them to change it themselves and re-test than to negotiate a change request with a contractor to change the code.

Comment: Forget the UI, and assume everyone knows how to use yaml or something.

Comment: @OrangeDog: OK you use YAML for configuring the logic in the example. Since the logic includes conditional rules, you find a way to represent these conditionals in YAML. Congratulations, you have reinvented Python. Why not write the whole app in Python then?

Comment: I'm not arguing against Alex, nor making any assumptions about what values are being changed. I'm just saying that it is not always the case that changing code is no harder than changing configuration. If that were true, then external configuration would not exist for anything.

Comment: @OrangeDog: I dont think anybody have argued that changing code will *always* be no harder than changing configurations. Obviously it depends on the code, configuration system and deployment procedure. However, if the configuration encodes business logic (as is the case in the example), then the configuration files needs to be under source control and part of the general test, build and deployment process. So it probably wouldn't be easier than changing code.

Answer (score 27):

The article goes on to talk about 'Enterprise Rule Engine's which are probably a better example of what he is arguing against.

The logic is that you can generalize to the point at which your configuration becomes so complicated that it contains its own programming language.

For instance, the state code to document mapping in the example could be moved to a configuration file. But you would then need to express a complex relationship.

```xml
<statecode id="AZ">
    <document id="SR008-04X"/>
    <document id="SR008-04XI"/>
</statecode>
```

Maybe you would also put the ledger amount in?

```xml
<statecode id="ALL">
    <document id="AUTHLDG-1A" rule="ledgerAmt >= 50000"/>
</statecode>
```

Soon you find that you are programming in a new language you have invented and saving that code in configuration files which have no source or change control.

It should be noted that this article is from 2007 when this kind of thing was a common approach.

Nowadays we would probably solve the issue with [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI). I.e., you would have a 'hard coded'

```
InvoiceRules_America2007 : InvoiceRules
```

which you would replace with a hard coded, or more configurable

```
InvoiceRules_America2008 : InvoiceRules
```

when the law or business requirements changed.

Comment: Perhaps you should define "DI". And maybe explain a bit more.

Comment: Why would that file not be in the source control system?

Comment: @JDługosz What if the file is client/user-specific? What if that file is *written and managed* by that client/user? What if that config is not a file but a row in a database? All real possibilities that could prevent it from being in source control.

Comment: If it's client specific, does the coded version have a huge mess of `if` statements to give different values for each client? That sounds like something that *should* be in a config file.  Being in one kind of file or another, all else being equal, is not a reason to not control/track/backup the file. @ewan seems to be saying that a DSL's file can't be saved as part of the project for some reason, when even non-code assets like images and sound files and documentation certainly *is*.

Comment: Right, if you use a DSL you should make sure that all the code that ends up in the DSL is unit-testable.  DSLs often have poorer language infrastructure for that kind of thing.

Comment: You should really refactor the "50000" value out of your XML and put it in a separate config file, don't you think?  ...and it's supposed to be 500000, by the way.

Comment: @jdlugosz the concept of an ERE is that you buy the system and then configure it for your needs. perhaps because internal devs were in competion with these 'flexible' systems they would try to emulate them. change control of the config, even in systems from big companies like IBM was often an afterthought. The selling point was quick change

Comment: I think that not controlling all source-like assets is a different issue entirely.  We're looking at code that is equivalent to in-shop source code, so making it a non-code file is still part of the project on the developer's side.  Saying "don't do X because some anti-patterns exist involving X" might be over-cautions and is missing the real information.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment. But the question isnt about best practice, its 'whats this 9 year old blog article complaining about?'

Answer (score 17):

> On the contrary, "500000" is not simply a number. It's a significant
>   value, one that represents the idea of a breakpoint in functionality.
>   This number could be used in more than one places, but it's not the
>   number that you're using, it's the idea of the limit/borderline, below
>   which one rule applies, and above which another.

And that is expressed by having (and I could argue that even the comment is redundant):

```
 if (ledgerAmnt >= 500000) {
    //Ledger of 500K or more requires AUTHLDG-1A
    attachDocument("AUTHLDG-1A");
  }
```

This is just repeating what the code is doing:

```
LEDGER_AMOUNT_REQUIRING_AUTHLDG1A=500000
if (ledgerAmnt >= LEDGER_AMOUNT_REQUIRING_AUTHLDG1A) {
    //Ledger of 500K or more requires AUTHLDG-1A
    attachDocument("AUTHLDG-1A");
}
```

Note that the author assumes that the meaning of 500000 is tied to this rule; it is not a value that is or is likely to be reused elsewhere:

> The one and only business rule change that this preceding Soft Coding
>   could ever account for is a change in the ledger amount that required
>   a form AUTHLDG-1A. Any other business rule change would require even
>   more work – configuration, documentation, code, etc

The article's main point, in my view, is that sometimes a number is just a number: it has no extra meaning other that what's conveyed in the code and it's not likely to be used elsewhere. Therefore, awkwardly summarizing what the code is doing (now) in a variable name just for the sake of avoiding hard-coded values is unnecessary repetition at best.

Comment: If you introduced the constant `LEDGER_AMOUNT_REQUIRING_AUTHLDG1A`, you wouldn't write the comment into the code anymore. Comments are not maintained well by programmers. If the amount ever changed, the `if` condition and the comment would get out of sync. On the contrary, the constant `LEDGER_AMOUNT_REQUIRING_AUTHLDG1A` never gets out of sync with itself and it explains its purpose without the needless comment.

Comment: @ZeroOne: Except that if the business rule changes to "Ledger of 500K or more requires AUTHLDG-1A and AUTHLDG-2B", it's very likely that the person who adds the `attachDocument("AUTHLDG-2B");` line will fail to update the constant-name at the same time. In this case, I think the code is quite clear enough with *neither* a comment *nor* an explainer variable. (Though it might make sense to have a convention of indicating the appropriate section of the business requirements document via code comments. Under such a convention, a code comment that does *that* would be appropriate here.)

Comment: @ruakh, OK, then I'd refactor the constant to be called `LEDGER_AMOUNT_REQUIRING_ADDITIONAL_DOCUMENTS` (which I probably should've done in the first place). I'm also in the habit of putting the business requirement IDs into the Git commit messages, not into the source code.

Comment: @ZeroOne: But there may be yet other documents with different ledger amount thresholds.

Comment: @ruakh, OK, then I'd create a map (aka. dictionary) data structure where the key is the minimum amount and the value is the set of document names. Then I'd loop those and add the documents that match the required minimum amount. (Something like `LinkedHashMap<Long, Set<String>> ADDITIONAL_DOCUMENTS_BY_MINIMUM_AMOUNT` if it was Java.)

Comment: @ZeroOne: But for AUTHLDG-3C the ledger amount is actually a *maximum*. And for AUTHLDG-4D the appropriate ledger amount depends on the state. (Do you get the point yet? For this type of code, you want your code to reflect the business rules, not some attempted abstraction of the business rules, because there's no reason to expect the evolution of the business rules to line up with the abstractions you've adopted.)

Comment: @ruakh, I guess we are losing the point here. I originally only said that using an appropriately named constant would make more sense than using a magic number plus a comment in the code. While configuration management and generic business rules engines are very interesting topics, I don't think this comment thread is the appropriate place to discuss them. :)

Comment: Personally, I don't object to putting the magic number in code, I object to structuring the code so it needs these comments. If it was me, I'd make each document an enum instance with its own `attachIfNecessary()` method and just loop over all of them.

Comment: @ZeroOne While I agree that `magic number + comment < constant`, I think that the comment is completely unnecessary with or without a constant as the code is pretty self-explanatory. I also fear that even the constant will get out of sync, especially if it's buried in a config file or a database (as long as there's no safe automatic way to rename everything in one step).

Answer (score 8):

The other answers are correct, and thoughtful. But here is my short-and-sweet answer.

```
  Rule/value          |      At Runtime, rule/value…
  appears in code:    |   …Is fixed          …Changes
----------------------|------------------------------------
                      |                 |
  Once                |   Hard-code     |   Externalize
                      |                 |   (soft-code)
                      |                 |
                      |------------------------------------
                      |                 |
  More than once      |   Soft-code     |   Externalize
                      |   (internal)    |   (soft-code)
                      |                 |
                      |------------------------------------
```

If the rules and special values appear in one place in the code, and do not change during runtime, then hard-code as shown in the question.

If the rules or special values appear in more than one place in the code, and do not change during runtime, then soft-code. Soft-coding for a rule might me defining a specific class/method or use the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). For values, soft-coding can mean defining a single constant or enum for the value to be used across your code.

If the rules or special values may change during runtime, then you must externalize them. It is commonly done by updating values in a database. Or update values in memory manually by a user entering data. It is also done by storing values in a text file (XML, JSON, plain text, whatever) that is repeatedly scanned for file modification date-time change.

Comment: I like your answer, but I think you should also consider whether it changes at implementation. This is mainly relevant if the thing is a product that will be used in many organisations which might, for example, have different rules over whether a supervisor needs to approve a refund over X, etc etc.

Comment: Agreed both with this answer and the comment about implementation. Stuff I work on is implemented by many organisations, and many of them have subtly different values needed. We tend to store these 'settings' in a database rather than config file, but the principle is that we don't want to make different builds of our software for each company that implements it (then repeat those different builds each time they upgrade).

Answer (score 7):

This is the trap we fall into when we use a **toy problem** and then pose only **strawman** solutions, when we are trying to illustrate a real issue.

In the example given, it makes not one whit of difference whether the values given are hardcoded as inline values, or defined as consts.

It is the surrounding code that would make the example a maintenance and coding horror. If there *is* no surrounding code, then the snippet is fine, at least in an environment of constant refactoring. In an environment where refactoring tends not to happen, the maintainers of that code are already dead, for reasons that will shortly become obvious.

See, if there is code surrounding it, then bad things clearly happen.

The first bad thing is that the value 50000 gets used for another value somewhere, say, the ledger amount over which the tax rate changes in some states... then when change happens, the maintainer has no way of knowing, when he finds those two instances of 50000 in the code, whether they mean the same 50k, or entirely unrelated 50ks. And should you also search for 49999 and 50001, in case someone used those as constants, too? This is not a call to plonk those variables in a config file of a separate service: but hardcoding them inline is clearly also wrong. Instead, they should be constants, defined and scoped within the class or file in which they are used. If the two instances of 50k use the same constant, then they likely represent the same legislative restriction; if not, they probably don't; and either way, they will have a name, which will be less opaque than an inline number.

The filenames are being passed to a function - attachDocument() - which accepts base filenames as string, without path or extension. The filenames are, essentially, foreign keys to some filesystem, or database, or wherever attachDocument() gets the files from. But the strings tell you nothing about this - how many files are there? What types of file are they? How do you know, when opening into a new market, whether you need to update this function? To what types of thing can they be attached? The maintainer is left entirely in the dark, and all he has is a string, which may appear multiple times in the code and mean different things every time it appears. In one place, "SR008-04X" is a cheat code. In another, it's a command to order four SR008 booster rockets. Here, it's a filename? Are these related? Someone just changed that function to mention another file, "CLIENT". Then you, poor maintainer, have been told that the "CLIENT" file needs to be renamed to "CUSTOMER". But the string "CLIENT" appears 937 times in the code... where do you even start looking?

The **toy problem** is that the values are all unusual and can be reasonably guaranteed to be unique in the code. Not "1" or "10" but "50,000". Not "client" or "report" but "SR008-04X".

The **strawman** is that the only other way to address the problem of impenetrably opaque constants is to hive them off into the config file of some unrelated service.

Together, you can use these two fallacies to prove any argument true.

Comment: Not a toy problem, not a strawman. This is something you'll see *all the time* in these kinds of business applications. There's no "opening into a new market", there's no reuse of the same number (after all, that would give it another meaning anyway) and in any case, the article says nothing against DRY - if there's two dependencies on the value, it will be either moved into a method or a constant. Show examples of how those constants (of config settings, it doesn't really matter) should be named, and where they should be stored in a way that's future proof and more clear than the code.

Comment: The example doesn't break down because it's a toy problem. The surrounding code will always be horrible because **the business rules that the software has to execute are horror**. Attempts to side-step this fundamental challenge with rules engines and DSLs and whatnot is often *programmer procrastination*, because solving CS problems is more enjoyable than solving intricacies of tax forms. Attempts at achieving 'elegance' are often fool's errands because the ultimate task of the software is to model a complicated disaster.

Comment: The business rules may be horror, but that's not in itself an excuse for writing this kind of mediocre procedural code. (I tend to agree with Papadimoulis that it's easier to model and maintain the rules in code than in configuration, I just think it should be better code.) The DRY problem I see isn't the magic numbers, it's the repeated `if (...) { attachDocument(...); }`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in this.

One issue is wether a rules engine should be build to make all rules easily configurable outside the program itself. The answer in cases similar to this is most often no. The rules will be changing in strange ways that are hard to predict which means that the rules engine has to be extended whenever there is a change.

Another issue is how to handle these rules and their changes in your version control. The best solution here is to split the rules into a class for each rule.

That allows for each rule to have its own validity, some rules change each year, some change depeding on when a permit have been given or an invoice is issued. The rule itself containing the check for which version it has to apply.

Also as the constant is private it cannot be misused anywhere else in the code.

Then have a list of all rules and apply the list.

A further issue is how to handle constants. 500000 might look inconspicuous but very great care has to be taken to make sure it gets converted correctly. If any floating point arithmetic is applied it might be converted to 500,000.00001 so a comparison with 500,000.00000 might fail. Or even worse 500000 always works as intended, but somehow 565000 fails when converted. Make sure the conversion is explicit and made by you not by the compiler guessing. Often this is done by converting it to some BigInteger or BigDecimal before it is used.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not directly mentioned in the question, I'd like to note that what's important is not to *bury* business logic in code.

Code, like the example above, that *encodes* externally specified business requirements should really live in a distinct part of the source tree, perhaps named `businesslogic` or something similar, and care should be taken to ensure that it *only* encodes the business requirements as simply, readably and concisely as possible, with a minimum of boilerplate and with clear and informative comments.

It should *not* be mixed with "infrastructure" code that *implements* the functionality needed to carry out the business logic, such as, say, the implementation of the `attachDocument()` method in the example, or e.g. UI, logging or database code in general.  While *one* way to enforce this separation is to "soft code" all the business logic in a config file, this is far from the only (or the best) method.

Such business logic code should also be written clearly enough that, if you showed it to a business domain expert with no coding skills, they'd be able to make sense of it.  At the very least, if and when the business requirements change, the code that encodes them should be clear enough that even a new programmer with no prior familiary with the codebase should be able to easily locate, review and update the business logic, assuming that no qualitatively new functionality is required.

Ideally, such code would also be written in a domain-specific language to enforce the separation between business logic and the underlying infrastructure, but that may be needlessly complicated for a basic in-house app.  That said, if you're e.g. selling the software to multiple clients that each need their own custom set of business rules, a simple domain-specific scripting language (perhaps e.g. based on a [Lua sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox)) might be just the thing.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking!!! When logic is buried deep in code, how can a domain/subject matter expert or business user see the values and logic that are in use in order to ensure they are right, and diagnose the system's behavior? One thing a config file does is make the settings *visible*. There has to be some means for promoting the visibility of business rules--even if that makes the coding "harder". I can accept a thin class or set of classes that do the job, without mixing in other concerns--as long as the business user has the means to access and understand them.